# How can I add/remove an element in a table/metatable? - Lua Script

Tags: data-structures, lua

Well, I know how to create a table/metatable with their initial values, but I don't know how to insert or remove an element after its creation. How can I do this using the best practice in Lua Script? Is there any kind of standart function to do this?

Comment: Did you bother to throw even one look at manual?

Comment: You are right, sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's just about every way of inserting and removing from Lua tables; firstly, for array-style tables:

```
local t = { 1, 2, 3 }

-- add an item at the end of the table
table.insert(t, "four")
t[#t+1] = 5  -- this is faster

-- insert an item at position two, moving subsequent entries up
table.insert(t, 2, "one and a half")

-- replace the item at position two
t[2] = "two"

-- remove the item at position two, moving subsequent entries down
table.remove(t, 2)
```

And for hash-style tables:

```
local t = { a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 }

-- add an item to the table
t["d"] = 4
t.e = 5

-- remove an item from the table
t.e = nil
```

Comment: Nice, but what is that operator '#', what does it do?

Comment: `#` is the length operator; by default it returns the number of entries in an array-style table, or the number of bytes in a string.  Note that it doesn't work with hash-style tables.

Comment: @LuizR.P.Santiago: You know, Lua has very comprehensive documentation. You might want to look to it sometime.